# Swift P.Protocol vs P.Type

Tags: swift, protocols

The following seems to work:

```
protocol P {}
class C: P {}
let c = C()
func foo<T>(_ t: T.Type) -> T? { return c as? T }
let p = foo(P.self)
print(type(of: p))   //  Optional<P>
```

But how, exactly?

- If the type of `p` is `P?`, that means that `T === P` in `foo()`, correct?
- And that means that the type of the `t` parameter of `foo()` is `P.Type`.
- The type of `P.self` is `P.Protocol`.
- So we're passing a `P.Protocol` to `foo()`, where it gets converted to `P.Type`.
- But why doesn't such a conversion fail? It's documented that a protocol
  does not conform to itself.
- And indeed, doing `let pt: P.Type = P.self` does fail.
- What's the difference between the direct `P.Protocol -> P.Type` conversion that fails,
  and the implicit conversion that happens when calling `foo(P.self)`?

Comment: Ah, couldn't find an answer for hours, found it minutes after posting. https://github.com/DevAndArtist/swift-evolution/blob/refactor_existential_metatypes/proposals/0126-refactor-metatypes.md "a generic type always uses T.Type to refer to the type of T.self. So when Proto is bound to a generic parameter P, P.Type is the same as Proto.Protocol."

Comment: See also https://forums.swift.org/t/metatypes-in-swift/16851/6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`P.Protocol` *is* the metatype for the protocol `P`, just like `T.Type` *is* the metatype for the non-protocol type `T`. There is no "conversions" going on.

So what is `P.Type` then?

`P.Type` is an existential metatype. There is no corresponding thing for non-protocol types. Say you want to store metatypes of concrete types that conform to `P`, you can store it in `P.Type`:

```
let x: P.Type = C.self
```

Note that `P.Type` can only store metatypes of concrete types, and `P.Protocol` can only store metatypes of protocols. To see why this division is significant, let's say `P` defines the static method `foo`, you can then call `x.foo()`. This is guaranteed to work because `P.Type` must have a concrete type, which will implement `foo`. On the other hand, you can't call `foo` on `P.Protocol`, because there is no implementation of `foo` in `P`.

See also: https://swiftrocks.com/whats-type-and-self-swift-metatypes

Comment: Yeah, but that's the point, I'm not calling `foo(C.self)`, I'm calling `foo(P.self)`. And the type of `P.self` is `P.Protocol`, not `P.Type`. But the parameter that `foo()` takes is `.Type`, not `.Protocol`. According to you definitions (if I understand them correctly), `foo(_: T.Type)` should only accept metatype instances of concrete types, but `P.self` is not one of those. Am I still missing something?

Comment: @imre The syntax is a bit misleading here. `T.Type` where `T` is a generic parameter "looks like" it only accepts stuff that ends in `.Type`. But really it just means "the _metatype_ of `T`". As I said, `P.Type` is not the metatype of `P`. `P.Protocol` _is_.

Comment: @imre So to summarise. If you have a concrete type `T`, its meta type is `T.Type`. If you have a protocol `P`, its metatype is `P.Protocol`. If you have a generic parameter `T` that can be a protocol or a concrete type, you use `T.Type` to mean the metatype of that generic parameter.

Comment: Yes, I was missing the "special" behavior of `T.Type` if `T` is a generic parameter. Thanks for the clarification.